# (Realm Error) Extension not initialized yet, couldn't access compileSdkVersion

Tags: react-native, realm, react-native-cli

I try to build an application in my MacBook and it doesn't build with realm. Two errors occur when I wanna build on android:

1) A problem occurred configuring project ':realm'.
2) A problem occurred evaluating project ':realm'. Extension not initialized yet, couldn't access compileSdkVersion. and in iOS, it says it couldn't find the realm constructor.

I've already checked the compilesdk versions on the main gradle file and in the realm module's gradle file. they look fine.

Comment: Any luck with that?

Comment: @BanAnanas yeah, I think. wassup??

Comment: Can you please answer your own question or point me to the solution? I'm getting the same error.

Comment: @BanAnanas which version of react, react native, and realm js do you use?? I think its about compatibility of each others because I have done it before

Comment: react 16.12.0
react-native 0.61.5
realm js 3.6.0

Comment: yeah as I assumed that realm js (at latest version per Jan 7, 2020) didn't compatible yet with the current react-native latest version that supports Hermes engine. I suggest you downgrade your react  native version or dont use hermes engine because realm js not supported yet with that. cmiiw